# Geolocation does not work in google chrome

Tags: google-geolocation

Is geolocation google. Example took from here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation?hl=ru . Copied JAVASCRIPT + HTML and placed on a virtual host http://test.ru on localhost.Created a browser key and added it. The map is loaded, but not running geolocation in google chrome. Tell me what the problem is. Here is the code:

```
 // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
// prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
// failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
// locate you.
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 6
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  var pos = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  };
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
  map.setCenter(pos);
}, function() {
  handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
});
  } else {
// Browser doesn't support Geolocation
handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
 }
 }
function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                    'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                    'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}`
```

Comment: you getting any error on console? Make sure you allow location service on your chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that since chrome 50, a security update removes the posibility of geolocation without http**s** protocol. since you are trying this url  **http**://test.ru it will not work.
[Google details](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only)

Hope it helps.
Regards.